Problems with createdTimestamp discord.js V14.15.3
My problem is the i get an error where interaction.createdTimestamp, is undefined
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Responds with bot and your ping'),
        async execute(client, interaction){
            const thinking = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor('Red')
                .setAuthor({name: 'I am thinking', iconURL: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExcmEydTFmcTAzMGR4dmYzc2pvdnpwdmlpb3FseHpnaDlkbHBybnAxNyZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9cw/TNRDoCRLlOqgbtqQh0/giphy.gif'})
            const thinked = new EmbedBuilder()
                .addFields(
                    {name: 'Ping', value: `${interaction.createdTimestamp - Date.now()}ms`},
                    {name: 'API latency', value: `${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`}
                )
            await interaction.reply({embeds: [thinking], ephemeral: true});
            await wait(2_000);
            await interaction.editReply({embeds: [thinked], ephemeral: true})

        }
}

And the error is this one:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createdTimestamp')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\cotug\Desktop\DiscordBots\EJGames\commands\utility\ping.js:13:58)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\cotug\Desktop\DiscordBots\EJGames\events\interactionCreate.js:16:18)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cotug\Desktop\DiscordBots\EJGames\main.js:37:44)
    at Client.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\cotug\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\cotug\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\cotug\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:355:31)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cotug\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:239:12)
    at WebSocketManager.emit (C:\Users\cotug\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.cjs:282:31)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cotug\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1190:51)


I tried to search it up but doesn't work with anything

It means interaction is undefined. How do you call execute()? Can you edit your post with it?

@ZsoltMeszaros, What you mean, sorry I am a bit new

@ZsoltMeszaros I found the problem, I apssed client before interaction, thank you anyways
